# Sizes of Quotient Rings of DVRs with Finite Residue Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is a discrete valuation ring (DVR) with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is finite, then all quotient rings of $R,$ namely $R/\mathfrak{m}^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N},$ are finite. My question is:

> Can we say anything about the sizes of $R/\mathfrak{m}^n$ for $n>1,$ if
>   we know $\#(R/\mathfrak{m})$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a short exact sequence: $$0\to\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\to R/\mathfrak m^2\to R/\mathfrak m \to 0.$$ Since $\dim_{R/\mathfrak m}\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2=1$ we get $\#(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2)=\#(R/\mathfrak{m})$. It follows that $\#(R/\mathfrak m^2)=\#(R/\mathfrak{m})^2$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: In fact, $m^i/m^{i+1}\simeq R/m$ since $m^i=(t^i)$ where $t$ is an uniformizing parameter.